# SELinux crashed data system

Tags: centos, selinux

I wanted to change the type of some data for SELinux and I made a typo and sent the following command into the prompt as the root user:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t openvpn _etc_t /
```

Now my system (CentOS 7) won't start up which is truely happened because of this command. The following things failed to start:

- resets system activity log
- login service
- dump dmeg
- network manager and several other things

Is there a chance to rescue my system?

Comment: Probably you can boot a livecd, mount the / partition, disable selinux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to relabel your file system.

This is the procedure to achieve this

1) When booting and the `grub` menu is shown, press `e` to enter grub.

2) Go to the line that starts with `linux16 ...`.

3) remove the `rhgb quiet` and append `rd.break`

4) Press `CTRL+x` to boot from grub

5) Now you'll see the shell

6) `mount -o remount,rw /sysroot`

7) `chroot /sysroot`

8) `touch /.autorelabel`

9) `CTRL+D`

10) `CTRL+D`

11) The system will relabel the filesystem using `fixfiles relabel` in the background

12) If the above steps are performed correctly you'll be able to boot without a problem

Comment: This didn't really help. Failed to start: [avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack, Dump dmesg, system logging service, resets system activity logs, login service, ntp client/server, network manager] and dependency failed for network manager wait online.

Comment: Well the procedure above doesn't get you to mDNS/DNS-SD.  It breaks in a very early stage of `initramfs`  At this point nothing really is mounted or loaded.

Comment: So... Is there another chance?

Comment: You could try the same and use  `systemd.unit=emergency.target`  in the same line but this time don't include `rd.break`.  Try to restore the SELinux context from there.  Can you update your question and explain what you tried. Did it allow you to enter the `grub` menu?  Did it responde to the commands I described above in my answer section?